# Split protocol name from URL

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Trying to split the `http://` from `http://url.com/xxyjz.jpg` with the following:

```
var imgUrl = val['url'].split(/(^http:\/\/)/);
```

And, even though I can get my desired result with the code above, I get some extra parameters that I would like not to have.

Output:

> ["", "http://", "url.com/xxyjz.jpg"]

So, the question is: What am I doing wrong that I get the extra `""`, besides the `"http://"`?

Comment: The quotes are there just to indicate that it's a string. Try placing the single value in a div and see, it won't have the quotes.

Comment: @panpiper OP means the first element in the array (an empty string), not the quotes around the protocol

Comment: oh, because you're using split. What is between http://? nothing (empty string) and "url....".

Comment: @panpiper lol! Sry if I miss expressed myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `match` instead of `split`:

```
var matches = str.match(/(http:\/\/)(.*)/).slice(1);
```

That will give you the array you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can just reference the index:

```
var a=str.match(/http:\/\/(.*)/)[1]
```